# Have a column equal to count of another table?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to have one column equal the count of all the rows in a different table where the id = a column in the current row?

For example.

- table1 has the columns: id, count
- table2 has the columns id, table1_id

I want the table1.count to automatically be filled with the amount of rows in table2 where `table2.table1_id = table1.id`

(its a parent child has one relationship).

Obviously i can just do this with php, i just figured this would be faster than to have to recount this constantly using php every time the page loads. Thanks.

Comment: Does the other one have to be a table, can't it be a view?

Comment: Yes, must be a table. Theres more to the table than what i showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a view and a table `table1_data`, you could do this:

```
CREATE VIEW table1 AS
SELECT table1_data.*, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table1_data, table2
WHERE table1_data.id = table2.table1_id
GROUP BY table1_data.id
```

This will take all the data from `table1_data`, add a column `count` as you described it, and present the result as a view which can be used just like a table in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html). It will probably recalculate the number each time, though.

To update a regular table each time another one is changed, use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html).

Don't worry too much about recalculationif the table is seldom changed bcause the result will usually be in the query cache.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `table1.id` is a unique key, you can do the following:

```
REPLACE INTO table1 (id, count)
SELECT table1_id, COUNT(*)
FROM table2
GROUP BY table1_id
```

Comment: Well it needs to be automated so that whenever table2 is update, table1 will update the count

Comment: When you want automatic updates, you want a view not a table. You can construct a view from a static table and a select to add the counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this "automatic" effect using triggers, of course if your DB engine supports them.
You would need to establish 2 triggers on your table_data, onInsert() and onDelete().